# Checking csv file max column length for multiple files

Tags: bash, csv, unix

I have a shell script that finds the maximum character length for each column (excluding the header) and then prints it out - all this works fine when I pass in a single using this command:

```
awk -F',' -f /cygdrive/c/temp/test2.awk /cygdrive/c/temp/files/testFile1.csv
```

However, the files directory contains more files named like testFile2.csv and so on. I ran the above command for each file and discovered that the first column does not exceed the length of 7 characters (excluding the header) but the command below returns the value 9 (meaning it is including the header in the calculation - why is it doing that?):

```
awk -F',' -f /cygdrive/c/temp/test2.awk /cygdrive/c/temp/files/testFile*.csv
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
NR==1{
    for(n = 1; n <= NF; n++) {
       colname[n]=$n
    }
}
NR>1{
    for(n = 1; n <= NF; n++) {
        if (length($n)>maxlen[n])
            maxlen[n]=length($n)
    }
}
END {
        for (i in maxlen) {
                print colname[i], ":",maxlen[i];
        }
        print "----- Total columns: " i " -----";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution and now it works like a charm, ignoring all the headers in each file while finding the maximum character length for each column in each file.

Revised code:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
NR==1{
    for(n = 1; n <= NF; n++) {
       colname[n]=$n
    }
}
FNR==1{next}
NR>1{
    for(n = 1; n <= NF; n++) {
        if (length($n)>maxlen[n])
            maxlen[n]=length($n)
    }
}
END {
        for (i in maxlen) {
                print colname[i], ":",maxlen[i];
        }
        print "----- Total columns: " i " -----";
}
```

Comment: I made it work on Windows (with Gow installed), but one needs to replace ' sign with " sign in the awk command :)